# How to apply onClick on tr except one td?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I have this table in my react component. I need to apply `onClick` on all the `<tr>` but need to exclude last column(`<td>`).

Is is possible to do that?

```
<tr
  className="cursor-pointer"
  key={activity._id}
  onClick={() =>
    activeTab === "active"
      ? this.setState({ activity, completeModal: true })
      : this.setState({ activity, showModal: true })
  }
>
  <td>{moment(activity.date).format("MM/DD/YY h:mm a")}</td>
  <td>{activity.manifestNumber}</td>
  <td>
    <NumberFormat
      thousandSeparator={true}
      displayType={"text"}
      value={activity.grossWeight}
    />{" "}
    lbs
  </td>
  <td>{activity.facility.name}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` on the last `td`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava You nailed it. It works!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation()` on click of the last `td`:

```
<tr
  className="cursor-pointer"
  key={activity._id}
  onClick={() =>
    activeTab === "active"
      ? this.setState({ activity, completeModal: true })
      : this.setState({ activity, showModal: true })
  }
>
  <td>{moment(activity.date).format("MM/DD/YY h:mm a")}</td>
  <td>{activity.manifestNumber}</td>
  <td>
    <NumberFormat
      thousandSeparator={true}
      displayType={"text"}
      value={activity.grossWeight}
    />{" "}
    lbs
  </td>
  <td onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>{activity.facility.name}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give that last `td` an `id` attribute, you could use the `event.target.id` value in the `onClick` handler to not do anything if it matches that `id`, e.g.:

```
onClick={event => {
  if (event.target.id === 'someId') {
    return;
  }

  if (activeTab === "active") {
    this.setState({ activity, completeModal: true })
  }
  else {
    this.setState({ activity, showModal: true })
  }
}}

<td id={'someId'}>{activity.facility.name}</td>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-frog-o9dxr

Comment: I have tried this. I get `undefined` in `event.target.id`

Comment: interesting, I just tested it in a sandbox and got the `id`

Comment: Can you pls how me the link

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation`, only the **cellHandler** is called while the `TR's` click handler never fires.

```js
export default function App() {
  const rowHanlder = () => {
    console.log("rowHanlder");
  };

  const cellHandler = () => {
    console.log("cellHandler");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table border="1" cellpadding="4">
        <tr onClick={() => rowHanlder()}>
          <td>Cell #1</td>
          <td>Cell #2</td>
          <td
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              cellHandler();
            }}
          >
            Cell #3 - Second Last Cell
          </td>
          <td
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              cellHandler();
            }}
          >
            Cell #4 - Last Cell
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```